# How to create a vlookup with awk on tsv files

Tags: csv, awk, vlookup

I am trying to vlookup strings which include spaces (file1) on a tsv file (file2).

[file1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oycIb.png)
[file2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzbsN.png)

Wished Output:
[Wished Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLm1f.png)

The following command does a vlookup but it assumes spaces as field separator:

`awk 'FNR==NR{a[$3]=$1; next} { if ($1 in a) {print a[$1], $1}}' file2 file1`

so the output is:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6EMn.png)

Defining tab as separator is not not fetching any data:

`awk -F "/t" 'FNR==NR{a[$3]=$1; next} { if ($1 in a) {print a[$1], $1}}' file2 file1`

Comment: Why do you post pictures, and not text? it is only 4 or 5 lines of text!   Also, form the description you gave it is unclear what you really are trying to do.   and a tab should be defined as `"\t"`, not as `"/t"`.

Comment: Please post your actual data - we can't run pictures of it through `awk` to test our solutions.

Comment: Copy paste did not work well with my tsv files, so I added pictures of the data. However, after correcting tab to "\t" it worked. What I do here is a vlookup between two files searching for strings from one file to the other. The problem was that awk separated the columns on both tab and space. Just needed to change the separator to tab properly. Thank you Luuk.